# Should I use bootstrap or some another framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I am building a very simple website (4 pages) and also want to make responsive design.
Though I have a lot of experience with java, python, html, css, C#.... etc... this is my first time to build a responsive design.

The adaptations I need to do are MINOR. **I have only 4-5 small adaptations** e.g. "put the text above video on mobile and on the right in desktop" / "put the checkboxes in a column in mobile and in a line in mobile".

I have started reading about various frame works e.g. bootstrap, html.css...

p.s. I need it only for the purpose of this small website I am building.

**My Q is: Should I invest time reading and learning them (and which to learn?) or would it be faster and simpler just to do the adaptations with @media CSS queries?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can learn Bootstrap or any other framework to do it easily and quickly. Now, the world is ready to make a responsive website even without writing single line of media style. It is the responsibility of framework. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Imran. Would it be faster for me to do it with bootstrap than writing my media queries (I mean the learning curve) or would I eventually spend too much time reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Seems you are already familiar with css. Then the learning curve is very very low. It should not take more than one hour to learn bootstarp. Rest of time is needed for exploring the beauty of bootstrap.